# Sitecore query syntax: Select all female descendents whose parent isn't called Jack

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

Given a Sitecore content tree of Males and Females (each sex with own template) representing a family tree, how would I select all Female descendents of an item where the parent wasn't called Jack using Sitecore query?

Context: My context item is one of Bob's children. My query shouldn't return Bob himself. Bob also has hundreds of brothers with thousands of descendants that I really don't want appearing in my results.

- Bob

  - Sarah

    - Jim
    - Julie
  - John

    - Sue
    - Jack

      - Anne
  - Jack

    - Claire

      - Mary

The query should return: Sarah, Julie, Sue and Mary but not Anne or Claire.

I can select all female descendents of Bob with:

..//*[@@templateid='{insert female template id here}']

But how do I add the parent name != Jack clause?

Comment: Does it have to be a query or is using an index also an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had a "family root" node that did not represent a person by itself, you could do this:

```lua
/path/to/family root//*[@@name != 'Jack']/*[@@templateid = '{template id}']
```

In your case, you want only a certain person's descendants to be returned. The person themselves should not be included in the result set. In that case, the approach from your comment is the way to go:

```lua
..//*[../@@name != 'Jack' AND @@templateid = '{template id}']
```

The results of both queries will include Mary since her direct parent is not called Jack.

Comment: Doesn't that exclude Sarah as well? It seems to in my tests, as it's selecting children of descendents. I ended up using ..//*[../@@name != 'Jack' AND @@templateid='{insert female template id here}'] For the record, I'm actually running the query from one of Bob's children, hence the ../ at the query start.

Comment: @JamesWalford oh, I thought you were running it in the context of `Bob` and `..` was to get the root node.

Comment: So yeah, my way will work only if you have a base node that does not represent a person. Your way will work even when the base node is a person as well.

Comment: Sorry, my question was poor, which is what happens when I remove the real world and try and make it generic. I'll edit the Q and let you edit the A :-)